# How to open two powershell consoles that run commands and then go back to user input?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to run two commands, followed by more commands dependant on the outcome. What I usually do is just open two powershell consoles, type the commands in there, and enter further commands if necessary. I want to make a script that simplifies this process and removes all the copy pasting. Right now I have a batch file with the following inside:

```
start powershell "cd 'C:\Program Files\folder' ; ./program.exe argument"
start powershell "cd 'C:\Program Files\otherfolder' ; python ./pythonscript.py"
```

The issue with this is that once the scripts are done the windows are closed and I cannot interact with them. What I need is to not only see the output but also have a PS console open so I could perform further actions in those directories. That is to perfectly replicate how it worked when I did it manually. Any ideas?

Comment: ````-NoExit````?

Comment: @PetSerAl beautiful champ. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Have you tried utilising `Start`'s `/D` option? _(`Start /?` at the Command Prompt for more information.)_

Comment: @Compo I  haven't, but -NoExit is perfect for my use case